# Use a secondary router for VPN authentication

Tags: wireless-router, openvpn

I have the following setup:
- Router1 connected to the internet
- Router2 connected to Router1
- Both these routers are at home
- A freeradius and a vpn servers root servers somewhere else and they are working

What I'd like to do is to disallow anyone connected to Router2 to access the internet and instead, re-route him to the VPN server. 
So optimally the scenario should be

So how to stop the user from accessing the internet without first authenticating with VPN?

Let us assume for the sake of simplicity that both routers can support open-wrt dd-wrt etc...

Cheers

Comment: You could achieve this goal with one router using DD-WRT and the built in Iptable firewall. It has the capability to filter who uses the vpn according to IP, protocol, etc. You could control who gets what IP in it's DHCP config

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be done with most conventional commercial routers.

What you need to do is to set up a *captive portal*, which asks for the VPN access credentials. You will have to have the VPN connection already established on the router, and use the same credentials for access to the captive portal and to the VPN. This way, after checking the access credentials, the router will allow the client thru its connection, which is **already** routed thru the VPN.

Thus what you need is a router2 which can:

a. connect to a remote VPN;

b. host a captive portal.

AFAIK, this is done with specialized router OSes like OpenWRT. DD-WRT, Zeroshell,, and so on. You can easily find information about any of these by Googling. Alternatively, you can  also use a pc as router2, then if use *Debian* as an OS you can find [here](http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Setting_up_a_captive_portal_from_scratch_using_Debian) pretty detailed information.

If you wish to double check whether your router can carry out this task, you should search, in its Instructions Manual, for the keywords *Captive Portal* and *Connection to a VPN*.

Comment: Yes. Captive portal is probably the right way to go